# What is this initialization code in Redux?

Tags: redux

This was some code already in the repo I work. Looks like jQuery global is being declared.Going by the comments what's the need for garbage collection?

```
// Initialize application
global.$ = $
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
})

// Grab the state from a global variable injected into the server-generated HTML
const preloadedState = window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__
global.webSocketURL = preloadedState.webSocketURL

// Allow the passed state to be garbage-collected
delete window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise, I think it's setting up how jquery will handle ajax requests, and then it's taking a value from server rendered state. It's then disposing of that state as it's no longer needed.

---

First, set `global.$` to be whatever `$` is in this context. We can presume it's jquery, based on the next line.

```
global.$ = $
```

Setup jquery to use defaults for all ajax calls:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
```

I don't think this line does anything, to be honest:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
})
```

Get the state from `window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__`. You normally see this when there's been some kind of server side rendering.

```
const preloadedState = window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__
```

Set a global variable based on `webSocketURL` from the preloaded state

```
global.webSocketURL = preloadedState.webSocketURL
```

We could presume that the initial state (which was presumably rendered server side) is no longer needed and can now be deleted:

```
delete window.__APP_INITIAL_STATE__
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As the application doesn't involve SSR is it same to assume this block can be done away with?

Comment: imo it seems as though this isn't really doing anything useful. Do you know if the app uses jquery's ajax calls at all? Are you able to find anywhere where `global.webSocketUrl` is used?

Comment: Not used anywhere else. API calls are handled by axios.

Comment: Then I'd say you'd be safe to at least try removing it, it's hard to see how else this code could affect the app